# Kannel: how to send multipart messages?

Tags: sms, sms-gateway, kannel

Are there any special options that I need to send to be able to send multipart messages?

I’m submitting SMS to Kannel by accessing the following URL.
http://myipaddress:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?username=test&password=test&to=123456789&from=TEST&text=long_long_text

But instead of receiving the message itself I see some strange symbols on my phone, something similar to
4eX1-06I! … and it contains some not Latin symbols as well.

If I make the text shorter (less then 160) without changing anything else it works fine, so this is just multipart message problem.
If I set coding and charset (coding=1&charset=windows-1252) then my Samsung phone receives the message, but Nokia says “Unsupported message type”
http://myipaddress:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?coding=1&charset=windows-1252&username=test&password=test&to=123456789&from=TEST&text=long_long_text

I'm able to send unicode messages with
http://myipaddress:13013/cgi-bin/sendsms?coding=2&charset=utf-8&username=test&password=test&to=123456789&from=TEST&text=long_long_text
but in this case instead of sending 2 messages I'm sending 3, it's expensive, so I wouldn't like to go this way.

Kannel smsbox version 1.4.3

From my point of view multipart messages should be handled automatically by kannel, so I haven't done anything specially for that. I couldn't find anything related to multipart messages in kannel configuration. I even couldn't find anything about multipart messages in kannel users manual at all.

Here is PDU for both single message and multipart. I don't really see any difference.

PDU for multipart message (1st page)

```
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[vivacell2]: Manually forced source addr ton = 6, source add npi = 1
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[vivacell2]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 1
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[vivacell2]: Sending PDU:
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7efeec0008b0 dump:
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 601 = 0x00000259
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr: "Tiko"
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 1 = 0x00000001
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "37493544831"
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   esm_class: 3 = 0x00000003
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sm_length: 17 = 0x00000011
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   short_message: "lohellohellohello"
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[vivacell2]: Got PDU:
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7efeec0008b0 dump:
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 601 = 0x00000259
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   message_id: "6030df9059c3c143"
2012-01-06 13:50:39 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

PDU for multipart message (2nd page)

```
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Manually forced source addr ton = 6, source add npi = 1
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 1
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Sending PDU:
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7efeec0012c0 dump:
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 585 = 0x00000249
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr: "SenderName"
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 1 = 0x00000001
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "123456789"
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   esm_class: 67 = 0x00000043
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sm_length: 23 = 0x00000017
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   short_message:
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:    Octet string at 0x7efeec001860:
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      len:  23
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      size: 1024
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      immutable: 0
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      data: 05 00 03 0b 02 02 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c   ......lohellohel
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      data: 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f                              lohello
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG:    Octet string dump ends.
2012-01-06 13:44:02 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

This message was delivered and concatanated, but it is unreadable.

Single message (this one works fine)

```
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Manually forced source addr ton = 6, source add npi = 1
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Manually forced dest addr ton = 1, dest add npi = 1
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Sending PDU:
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7efeec0008b0 dump:
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 4 = 0x00000004
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 587 = 0x0000024b
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   service_type: NULL
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr_ton: 5 = 0x00000005
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr_npi: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   source_addr: "SenderName"
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   dest_addr_ton: 1 = 0x00000001
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   dest_addr_npi: 1 = 0x00000001
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   destination_addr: "123456789"
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   esm_class: 3 = 0x00000003
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   protocol_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   priority_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   schedule_delivery_time: NULL
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   validity_period: NULL
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   registered_delivery: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   replace_if_present_flag: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   data_coding: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sm_default_msg_id: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sm_length: 30 = 0x0000001e
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   short_message:
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:    Octet string at 0x7efeec000a80:
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      len:  30
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      size: 31
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      immutable: 0
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      data: 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68   hellohellohelloh
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:      data: 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f 68 65 6c 6c 6f         ellohellohello
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:    Octet string dump ends.
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP[mts]: Got PDU:
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU 0x7efeec0008b0 dump:
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   type_name: submit_sm_resp
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_id: 2147483652 = 0x80000004
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   command_status: 0 = 0x00000000
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   sequence_number: 587 = 0x0000024b
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG:   message_id: "6030df305bc3c1c2"
2012-01-06 13:44:22 [26630] [7] DEBUG: SMPP PDU dump ends.
```

Here is the smsc configuration.

```
group = smsc
smsc-id = mts
smsc = smpp
host = ipaddress
port = 2775
#receive-port = 2775
smsc-username = "********"
smsc-password = "********"
transceiver-mode = true
source-addr-ton = 6
source-addr-npi = 1
dest-addr-ton = 1
dest-addr-npi = 1
interface-version = "34"
system-type = "ESME"
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/smsc.log"
log-level = 4
#alt-addr-charset = GSM
alt-charset = GSM
msg-id-type=0x03
reconnect-delay = 1
keepalive = 60
connection-timeout = 600
#max-pending-submits=10
log-file = "/var/log/kannel/mts.log"
log-level = 0
```

How to solve that?
Please let me know if you need any other information.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste the relevant configuration section?

Comment: This seems like SMSC implementation error. In case of coding 0 is used this SMSC requires 7bit packed data instead of string with 7-bit characters.

Answer (score 1):

You can set below parameter to avoid duplicate message

```
sms-resend-retry = 0
max-messages =0
```

Answer (score 0):

In the Kannel user guide there's a `max-messages` setting,

> If the message to be sent is longer than maximum length of an SMS it
>   will be split into several parts. max-messages lets you specify a
>   maximum number of individual SMS messages that can be used. If
>   max-messages is set to 0, no reply is sent, except for error messages.

I'd try changing that setting because i don't seem to find a default anywhere

http://www.kannel.org/download/1.4.3/userguide-1.4.3/userguide.html

Comment: It looks like a coding issue. I set coding to 0, but I don't really understand why it doesn't work? Should kannel automatically pack the data or I should do it manually? Why the same works for short messages (< 160 symbols) and doesn't work for the long ones? I really don't see the difference.

Comment: Forgot to say, max-messages is set to 4, this doesn't help much.